# GWT maven compiler output directory

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I need to set output directory location for GWT compiler using maven plugin.

I've investigated the GWT compiler and gwt-maven-plugin docs and did not find any options for this.

For example:

I have two modules named `editor` and `console` and gwt-maven-plugin compiles them to `%ROOT%/editor` and `%ROOT%/console` dirs.

But I need to have these modules compiled into `%ROOT%/ria/editor` and `%ROOT%/ria/console` dirs to reduce effort to maintain the URL based security and other stuff.

Is it possible to set `ria` directory in plugin configuration to avoid unneeded new ANT task creation for moving compiled modules stuff to needed place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/ria</webappDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#webappDirectory

It won't play well with the DevMode though, unless you run in `-noserver` mode (which I'd recommend anyway for any middle-sized/big project)

Comment: works for me!. I have my web sources in webapp/my_project/ so i configured <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/my_project</warSourceDirectory> in gwt-maven-plugin and maven-war-plugin. I also configured the run target <runTarget>my_project/index.html</runTarget>, so gwt:run maven goal start in the right position.

Answer (score 17):

I had to un-check the checkbox highlighted in the below screenshot[image]