# The output directory for the project should be set to /gwtproject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

Tags: gwt, maven

I have created a GWT Maven project in Eclipse using New->Project->Maven project->GWT Eclipse plugin. It was created, but it gives some errors like

```
The output directory for the project should be set to /gwtproject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
```

Is anything missing while configuring my project?

My pom.xml includes:

```
<build>
        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>

                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: In the project classpath settings (project/Properties/Java Build Path/Sources tab) what is set for output path? Can you send a screenshot?

Comment: I answered a similar question and I believe the answer works in your case too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26359380/897041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the missing part in  `<webappDirectory>` tag in the pom. I think this should solve your problem: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354673/gwt-maven-compiler-output-directory)

Answer (score 7):

An eclipsy solution to this problem is:

1. Select the project in the Package Explorer.
2. Open the properties of the project.
3. Select Java Build Path
4. Change the default output folder[image]
5. Question the life decisions you made that landed you in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a pre-check with GWT Article WorkingWithMaven - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

Also refer GWT Sample project [Validation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation/pom.xml), [DynaTableRf](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/dynatablerf/pom.xml) and [MobileWebApp](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/pom.xml).